# PHP problema con clases abstractas y funciones protegidas

Tags: php, patrones-de-diseño, clase-abstracta

Como dice el titulo tengo un problema con el siguiente código.

```
abstract class AClass {
    abstract protected function a1();
    abstract protected function a2();

    public function show() {
        return $this->a1() . "<br>" . $this->a2();
    }
}


class A1 extends AClass {

    protected function a1() {
        return 'A1a1';
    }

    protected function a2() {
        return 'A1a2';
    }
}

class A2 extends AClass {

    protected function a1() {
        return 'A2a1';
    }

    protected function a2() {
        return 'A2a2';
    }
}

class AA {

    public function __construct() {
        $a11 = new A1();

        $a22 = new A2();

        $this->inter($a11);
        $this->inter($a22);
    }

    private function inter(AClass $class)  {
        echo $class->show();
    }
}

$aa = new AA();
```

Devuelve este error:

> Fatal error: Call to protected A1::a1() from context 'AA' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Learning\index.php on line 38

La linea 38 es esta:

```
$a11 = new A1();
```

No entiendo por que tira ese error en la linea si no estoy llamando a a1() en la misma.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Javier

Comment: Gracias Marcos, tienes razon

Answer (score 1):

Ok, el problema es que no conocía que PHP no es sensitivo a mayúsculas, entonces el método a1 esta siendo tomado como constructor.